# Glass quick start for .NET and refresh token

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I'm working with the MirrorQuickStart project for .NET and am running into problems with the refresh token. From what I can tell, it is not being used when the "notify" action comes in for a timeline subscription update.

Publishing the app to a dev server, basically as-is with the exception of updating the proper IDs and config info, the "notify" action works within the first hour, but after that, it stops responding until I refresh the web page and re-authenticate.

I have checked the StoredCredentials table on the database server, and it has the UserId, AccessToken and RefreshToken values populated. I also created a new mirror service in the standard app flow (since I'm not sure how to debug the notify flow and see any actual error messages that are occuring) and each time, I see the AccessToken and RefreshToken on the service.

```
MirrorService service = new MirrorService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
     Authenticator = Utils.GetAuthenticatorFromState(
             Utils.GetStoredCredentials(userId))
});
```

I've reviewed the DrEdit project for Drive and the flow seems to be basically the same in terms of the `GEtAuthenticatorFromState` and `GetStoredCredentials` methods.

This question seemed to most directly relate to the problem I'm encountering, but the answer didn't make sense in terms of the mirror project.

[How to generate access token using refresh token through Google Drive SDK in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458644/how-to-generate-access-token-using-refresh-token-through-google-drive-sdk-in-ne)

There's gotta be something simple I'm missing - just not sure as I'm fairly new to the OAuth flow.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get a specific error on the notify endpoint?

Comment: Been trying to debug a bit more - I think this logic should apply to the NotifyController, but I modified the MainController to use the "service" created by the code I included in the original post (I hard-coded by UserId for testing purposes). I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized error when I attempt to retrieve the list of subscriptions. In theory, that should be the same "service" that the NotifyController is attempting to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the other SO answer you linked to, this seems to solve the problem in `Model/Utils.cs`:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the IAuthorizationState stored in the StoredStateClient instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="provider">OAuth2 client.</param>
        /// <returns>The stored authorization state.</returns>
        static public IAuthorizationState GetState(StoredStateClient provider)
        {
            provider.RefreshToken(provider.State);
            return provider.State;
        }
```

Notice the added line: `provider.RefreshToken(provider.State)`. It's still unclear why the call to `RefreshToken` is required as this should be done automatically by the library...

Comment: Thank you - I'll give this a try and see what happens. To answer your previous question, I was able to get an error from the notify endpoint. Here's the stack trace: 
   at Google.Apis.Requests.Request.AsyncRequestResult.GetResponse()
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.GetResponse()
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Fetch()
   at MirrorQuickstart.Controllers.NotifyController.HandleTimelineNotification(Notification notification, MirrorService service)
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: The error seems related to the token not being refreshed. I'm still unsure why the explicit call needs to happen but will investigate more.

Comment: Ha - go figure, as soon as I start testing this, my daily usage quota is at the limit! I'll check into things tomorrow and hopefully mark this as an answer. Thanks again for the help, I appreciate it.