# Is it possible to connect to the Drive API in the background?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I want to save user's data in the background but I don't understand how to connect to the Drive API without user interaction.

From my understanding after the first connect

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}
```

I'd like to obtain a refresh token which I will use later on to get an access token which I'll use to connect to the API and save user's data. It doesn't look feasible with [Drive API for Android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/)

Also I'll appreciate if somebody points me towards how do it it the right way!

Answer (score 1):

To implement saving file to Drive from background service, you need to start an activity where you will be handling the activity result of the permission activity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    // permission is given
    finish();
  } else {
    or show error
  }
}
```

To obtain a [refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#incrementalAuth) to allow long-term access, your app requests authorization to access resources which are identified by scopes. You need to add `prompt=consent` parameter to the authentication request. When `prompt=consent` is included, the consent screen is displayed every time the you logs into your app. The refresh token is only returned the first time on granting the application permission.

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/google-oauth-refresh-token-is-not-being-received/10857806#10857806):

> The refresh_token is only provided on the first authorization from the user. Subsequent authorizations, such as the kind you make while testing an OAuth2 integration, will not return the refresh_token again.

Then to generate access token using refresh token, you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631042/how-to-generate-access-token-using-refresh-token-through-google-drive-api).

Comment: Could you provide a code example with request for authorization for Google Drive?

Comment: You need to use the [OAuth 2.0 protocol](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) for authenticating a Google account and authorizing access to user data. Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-auth) and [example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/auth/web-server#exchange_the_authorization_code_for_an_access_token).